# Issue with date formatting in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to format the date and having issues using the following:
`d <- format(Sys.time(), "%m/%d/%Y")`
sets d = 04/05/2022 as I'd expect.

When I convert d to a date using the following:
`d <- as.Date(d)`
That does convert it to a date datatype however the value becomes 4-05-20

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `as.Date(d, format="%m/%d/%Y")` will give the right answer.  The problem is that `as.Date()` assumes YYYY/MM/DD or YYYY-MM-DD formats by default for character strings.  Since your date is in a different format, the wrong answer gets returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a format in the `as.Date` function as well. The thing is that the order format is different from your system time, `Sys.Date`, and it uses `-` instead of `/`:

```
d <- format(Sys.Date(), "%m/%d/%Y")
d
```

Output:

```
[1] "04/05/2022"
```

When using `as.Date`:

```
as.Date(d, format =  "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Output:

```
[1] "2022-04-05"
```

As you can see it is actually the same but with different order and notation.